# Entity Framework Code First should return a value after a new record inserted?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to return effected row value which is PK. I am using Entity Framework Repository Patter.

below is my code:

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);            
            //context.Entry(entity).GetDatabaseValues();           
            int Effected_Row_Value= ?? //How ?
        }
```

after inserting the record should return PK value of newly created row.

Comment: The ID only gets assigned when you commit the entity. Call `SaveChanges` on the context, and then retrieve the id from the entity (`entity.Id`, or whatever the PK field is called).

Comment: Can you please expand your answer. My `SaveChanges()` method seems like below: `public void SaveChanges()`
`        {`
            `context.SaveChanges();`
`            //context.Entry       `
`           // var pkey = `DbSet.Create().GetType().GetProperty(entity.GetType().Name + "ID").GetValue(entity);          `
            
               
`        }`